# regex named group if exist

Tags: python, regex, grouping, named

Good morning,

I have a string that I need to parse and print the content of two named group knowing that one might not exist.

The string looks like this (basically content of /proc/pid/cmdline):

```
"""
<some chars with letters / numbers / space / punctuation> /CLASS_NAME:myapp.server.starter.StarterHome /PARAM_XX:value_XX /PARAM_XX:value_XX /CONFIG_FILE:myapp.server.config.myconfig.txt /PARAM_XX:value_XX /PARAM_XX:value_XX /PARAM_XX:value_XX <some chars with letters / numbers / space / punctuation>
"""
```

my processes have almost the same pattern, that is:

`/CLASS_NAME:myapp.server.starter.StarterHome` is always present, but
`/CONFIG_FILE:myapp.server.config.myconfig.txt` is NOT always present.

I'm using python2 with `re` module to catch the values. So far my pattern looks like this and I'm able to catch the value I want corresponding to `/CLASS_NAME`

```
re.compile('CLASS_NAME:\w+\W\w+\W\w+\W(?P<class>\w+)')
```

The because `/CONFIG_FILE` is present or not, I added the following to `myregexp`:

```
re.compile(r"""CLASS_NAME:\w+\W\w+\W\w+\W(?P<class>\w+).*?
               (CONFIG_FILE:\w+\W\w+\W\w+\W(?P<cnf>\w+.txt))?
            """, re.X)
```

My understanding is that the second part of my `rexexp` is optional because the whole part is between parenthesis followed by `?`.

Unfortunately my assumption is wrong as it couldn't catch it

I also tried by removing the 1st `?` but it didn't help.

I gave several tries through `PYTHEX` to try to understand my regexp but couldn't find a solution.

Could anyone have any suggestion to resolve my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the whole optional part within an optional non-capturing group and make the capturing group for `CONFIG_FILE` obligatory:

```
re.compile(r"""CLASS_NAME:(?:\w+\W+){3}(?P<class>\w+)(?:.*?
               (CONFIG_FILE:(?:\w+\W+){3}(?P<cnf>\w+\.txt)))?
        """, re.X)
```

In case there are newlines, use `re.X | re.S` modifier options. Note that `\w+\W\w+\W\w+\W` is better written as `(?:\w+\W+){3}`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wndSus/2)

The main difference is `(?:.*?(CONFIG_FILE:(?:\w+\W+){3}(?P<cnf>\w+\.txt)))?` part:

- `(?:` - start of an optional (as there is a greedy `?` quantifier after it) non-capturing group matching

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `(CONFIG_FILE:(?:\w+\W+){3}(?P<cnf>\w+\.txt))` - matches

    - `CONFIG_FILE:` - a literal substring
    - `(?:\w+\W+){3}` - three sequences of 1+ word chars followed with 1+ non-word chars
    - `(?P<cnf>\w+\.txt)` - Group `cnf`: 1+ word chars, a dot (note it should be escaped) and then `txt`
- `)?` - end of the optional non-capturing group (that will be tried once)

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor, it helped me a lot